# Can I control the name of forms when using a custom task process in SharePoint Designer?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, tasks

I use SPD 2010 to create a complex workflow. I use many custom task process to interact with the different users at different stages of the workflow.

Each time I add a new custom task process in my workflow, SPD create a content type named `Tâche _x0028_1_x0029_` and a corresponding `Tâche _x0028_1_x0029_.xsn` form (My SPD is in French, and unicode un-escaped, it is `Tâche (1)`).

Is there a way to control these names (without VS) ? When the workflow grows, it starts to be a mess.

PS: I've tried once to rename the contenttype, but not only the form name hasn't changed, but the workflow wasn't exportable anymore.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change these content type names.